# C++ Passing through a function an std::array of std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray

I'm new with std::array. I have to create this function

```
void foo(std::array < std::array <double, a>& , b> & previous)
```

where a and b are two fixed integer values.
How should I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see `a` there.

Comment: the first ("internal") `&` seems misplaced, instead if you're really after an array of array references (which seems unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

The "variables" `a` and `b` *must* be compile-time constants. If you want them to be variable or set during runtime, you must use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Template arguments (such as those to `std::array`) must be known at compile time. To be general, you can write a function that is templated on the two sizes, e.g.:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void foo(std::array<std::array<double, N>, M> &previous) {
    // code goes here, e.g.:
    previous[M - 1][N - 1] = static_cast<double>(M * N);
}
```

The template arguments will be deduced by the function argument type, so your array of arrays can have any dimensions you want and you don't need to specify them when calling `foo`.

```
std::array<std::array<double, 10>, 20> my_array;
foo(my_array); // equivalent to foo<10, 20>(my_array);
```

By the way, using `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` is a terrible, awful idea if you want your program to be robust or fast. Not only must you manually manange and carefully track each inner `vector`'s length, you also take a huge performance hit by individually heap-allocating `N` `M`-length arrays rather than, say, a single `N x M`-length array.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned pmttavara you can perform compile time deduction of the dimensions and type.

```
template <typename Scalar, std::size_t I, std::size_t J>
void
Foo(std::array<std::array<Scalar, I>, J>& previous) {
}

int main() {
        std::array<std::array<double, 10>, 20> data;
        Foo(data);
}
```

Alternatively you can treat this data like a matrix.

```
template <typename Scalar>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
        : rows(rows)
        , cols(cols)
        , data(rows * cols, Scalar(0))
    {}

    Scalar&
    at(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) {
        std::size_t n = (row * cols) + col;
        return data.at(n);
    }

private:
    std::size_t rows;
    std::size_t cols;
    std::vector<Scalar> data;
};

int main() {
        Matrix<double> m(3, 3);
        m.at(2, 2) = 3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`a` and `b` must be known at compil time. You can declare them as

```
constexpr int a = 10;
constexpr int b = 100;
```

If is not possible to know at compile-time this two variable you have to use `std::vectors` instead:

```
typedef std::vector< const std::vector > Matrix;
void f( const Matrix& m );
```

Comment: if m is readonly is a good idea, if not just a reference... I don't know the exact situation

Comment: exactly. OP does not use const reference, so why putting it without confirmation?

Comment: Please use using instead of typedef, and const std::vector? How do you populate that?